# Visual C++ 2008 Remote Debugger error/lack of functionality

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, remote-debugging

Devel PC is Windows 7 64-bit with Visual C++ 2008 installed as part of Visual Studio 2008 Professional with SP1 ( ver 9.0.30729.1 SP, .NET 3.5 SP1 ).

Hotfixes/security updates installed:
2538241
9448999
945282
946040
946308
946344
946581
947171
947173
947180
947540
947789
948127
953256
974479
945140
947888
948484
948560
956453
967143
2251487
2669970
973675

Target PC is Windows 7 64-bit without Visual C++ installed.

I compiled a basic debug console application ( 32-bit ), copied the .exe and .pdb files to the target PC, started the remote debugger ( x64 version ), and attached to the process from the devel PC. When doing this, no breakpoint is hit on the devel PC. Yes, it's a debug build; yes, a clean rebuild was done; yes, the files copied to the target PC are what was last build. I assume the breakpoint isn't hit because the app is 32-bit and the remote debugger is 64-bit. Thus, I close it and run the 32-bit version. Then, I receive an error that I can't start the app.

"Unable to start program .

An error occurred that usually indicates a corrupt installation (code 0x80004002). If the problem persists, repair your Visual Studio installation via 'Add or Remove Programs' in Control Panel."

I've done the repair, used the MS verify tool to check the .NET libraries, started Visual Studio in safe mode ( no change ), copied the debug DLLs to the target PC location ( network drive ) since this is a debug build, searched for a solution ( a lot tend to be regarding managed code which this definitely isn't ) and still can't get it run.  I tried connecting as another user to no avail.

Has anyone had this issue?

EDIT: so msvcm90d, msvcp90d, and msvcr90d DLLs in the directory don't allow the debug application to run ( not sure why ) but a configuration file in the same place redirects any older version of the DebugCRT to the newer version. The only folder in the sxs folder is for the newer version ( SP1 ). Removing the config file gives a sxs error.

Comment: some DLLs are missing, usually are the VC Runtime. You can use the tool "Dependency Walker" in VS to find what are missing in the target machine.

Comment: I tried that and Dependency Walker only showed GPSVC and IESHIMS as not found. A search on those seems to make it sound like those are okay.